# My workflow Tasks in liferay is empty every time

Tags: liferay, workflow

I am implementing custom portlet with kaleo workflow in liferay 6.2
when I save data, I can see status=1 which is pending. but then nothing show up in 
My Workflow Tasks, as pending or as complete.

I have two users, The first one(let us say x) is admin who tries to add data,
the other(let us say y) has content reviewer role so that he can approve the workflow.

what am I missing:
bellow is my code for my Workflow Handler class:

```
public class BookWorkflowHandler extends BaseWorkflowHandler{

    public String getClassName() {
        return CLASS_NAME;
    }
    public String getType(Locale locale) {
        return LanguageUtil.get(locale, "model.resource." + CLASS_NAME);
    }
    public Object updateStatus(int status,  Map<String, Serializable> workflowContext)  throws PortalException, SystemException {
        System.out.println("statu while updating in workflow handler"+status);
        long userId = GetterUtil.getLong(workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_USER_ID));
        long resourcePrimKey = GetterUtil.getLong(workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_ENTRY_CLASS_PK));
        ServiceContext serviceContext = (ServiceContext) workflowContext.get("serviceContext");
        System.out.println("statu while updating in workflow handler"+status);
        return BookLocalServiceUtil.updateStatus(userId, resourcePrimKey, status, serviceContext);

    }
    public static final String CLASS_NAME = Book.class.getName();
}
```

and here is my BookLocalSeviceImpl:

```
public class BookLocalServiceImpl extends BookLocalServiceBaseImpl {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public Book addBook(Book newBook, long userId,
            ServiceContext serviceContext)
                    throws SystemException, PortalException {
        Book book =
                bookPersistence.create(
                        counterLocalService.increment(Book.class.getName()));
        book.setCompanyId(newBook.getCompanyId());
        System.out.println("********group id********"+newBook.getGroupId());
        book.setGroupId(serviceContext.getScopeGroupId());
        book.setUserId(serviceContext.getUserId());
        book.setTitle(newBook.getTitle());
        book.setAuthor(newBook.getAuthor());
        book.setStatus(1);
        bookPersistence.update(book, false);

        assetEntryLocalService.updateEntry(
                userId, book.getGroupId(), Book.class.getName(),
                book.getBookId(), serviceContext.getAssetCategoryIds(),
                serviceContext.getAssetTagNames());
        book.setStatus(WorkflowConstants.STATUS_DRAFT);
        System.out.println("status while adding "+book.getStatus());
        WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.startWorkflowInstance(
                book.getCompanyId(), book.getGroupId(), userId,
                Book.class.getName(), book.getPrimaryKey(), book,
                serviceContext);

        return book;
    }

    @Override
    public Book updateStatus(long userId, long resourcePrimKey, int status, ServiceContext serviceContext)throws PortalException, SystemException {
            User user = userLocalService.getUser(userId);
            Book book = getBook(resourcePrimKey);
            book.setStatusByUserId(userId);
            book.setStatusByUserName(user.getFullName());
            book.setStatusDate(serviceContext.getModifiedDate());
            bookPersistence.update(book, false);
            System.out.println("status in updateStatus localService******"+status);
    if (status == WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED) {
        System.out.println("workflow approved");
        assetEntryLocalService.updateVisible(
                Book.class.getName(), resourcePrimKey, true);
    }
    else if(status==1) {
        System.out.println("workflow pending");
        assetEntryLocalService.updateVisible(
                Book.class.getName(), resourcePrimKey, false);
    }
    return book;
}


}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what's wrong, but I can help with some troubleshooting/code optimization tips:

1. Don't set the int "status" value yourself. Let Liferay do it. In the LocalServiceImpl add method, instead of `book.setStatus(1);` call `book.setStatus(WorkflowConstants.STATUS_DRAFT);`, which is actually the int value '2'.
2. In the LocalServiceImpl `updateStatus`method, just set the visibility to false for ALL assets that are not `APPROVED`, so instead of your `else if` statement, use

   else {

   ```
      assetEntryLocalService.updateVisible(Book.class.getName(),
         resourcePrimKey, false);
   }
   ```
3. Neither step 1 or 2 is likely to solve your problem though. Are you using the Single Approver Definition that comes with Liferay, or a different definition? If different, can you paste the definition here? I'd want to make sure that the proper roles are assigned to the review task. I'd also test the workflow with another entity to see if it's working properly.
4. The Liferay Developer Network (https://dev.liferay.com), the official site for Liferay Development Documentation, has a Learning Path on Enabling entities for workflow, that you might want to look at for code comparison purposes. https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/mvc/-/knowledge_base/6-2/approving-content-with-workflow

Comment: I am using single approver. I did your suggestions in 1 and 2, it didn't help. I have two specific questions: 1.I get :status while adding 2
statu while updating in workflow handler0
statu while updating in workflow handler0
status in updateStatus localService******0    as a test result. is this right?   2. what should be the setting for single approver or I have to use it as default setting?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your questions, can you clarify them? The Single Approver Definition has both Portal Content Reviewer and site Content Reviewer roles specified in the Review task Assignment, so it's not a problem with Role Assignments. But, just for a sanity check, perhaps you can test the workflow with another portlet's entities, like Web Content Articles.

Comment: Ok got it! so let us say I have two users, user1 and user2. what should be the role of user1 to request "add book" and what should be the role of user2 to act as reviewer?

Comment: User 1 would just need to be anyone with permission to add the Book entity, and User 2 would need to be any user with one or more of the following Roles: Organization Administrator, Organization Content Reviewer, Organization Owner, Administrator, Portal Content Reviewer, Site Administrator, Site Content Reviewer, Site Owner

Comment: Another Question: What have you set as your Primary Key in `service.xml`? Because you're using `resourcePrimKey` in your Workflow code and `bookId` in your asset code.

Comment: <column name="bookId" type="long" primary="true" />

Comment: Okay, then my next idea is to  substitute `bookId` where you're currently using `resourcePrimKey` in both the WorkflowHandler and the LocalServiceImpl.

Comment: However, I'm not sure what your `bookId` column looks like in the DB, because I don't see you setting it. You have `Book book =
                bookPersistence.create(
                        counterLocalService.increment(Book.class.getName()));` I'm accustomed to seeing something like this instead:

Comment: `long bookId = counterLocalService.increment();

  Book book = bookPersistence.create(bookId);`